# Which color Value for Highligting in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, highlighting, color-scheme

When I highlight a variable in Visual Studio the other appearances are also highlighted with a light gray background (standard behaviour from VS 2012)

I want to change that background color to a more "visible" color. I already installed the "Visual Studi 2012 Color Theme Editor" to be able to change individual colors.

I just do not know, what is the Name of that Color. I expect it to be under "All Elements - Editor - xxx" but which is the exact Name of that color?

Here is an example:

[image: How to change the gray background?]
(how do I change the gray backgrounds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it via *Options* -> *Enviroment* ->  *Fonts and Colors* -> *Diplay items* -> **Highlighted Reference**. "Visual Studi 2012 Color Theme Editor" is not necessary for this.

[image]